# Workaround for Android 6.0.1 Double Tap on power button

Tags: android

I have a service running on my app and I'm listening the power button press.

Succinctly, my app is a panic button that, when the user press the power button four times, it starts an service for sending the user's location.

My app works flawlessly on android 6-, but I faced a problem running it on a Nexus running Android 6.0.1, because the Double Tap to open camera.

There is a way of handling this on my app, or because this camera shortcut is a system service I can do nothing about?

Comment: You could ask users to disable the double tap to open camera (under Settings->Display).

Comment: Yeah, this is what I'm thinking about, but I can't force any user to disable the feature, it's not user friendly correct?

Comment: Yeah, you can't even tell if they have it on or not. Either way, they'd need to choose between your app and the camera functionality

Answer (score 0):

The final word is, no. There's no way to solve this. Since this functionality is Nexus exclusive, the user who want this can't use my app's functionality.